# Error: Unknown Import 'utils' But Code Works

Tags: python, import, pycharm

In my code I get this error telling me that it doesn't recognise my imports:

[image]

This has kind of fixed the problem, in VSCode, instead of opening a large folder which has other sub folder, I opened only 1 of the folders:

[image]

I am not sure what is causing this problem as, the code which I have written uses data and functions in the files from utils folder. This means that my app is running flawlessly with no errors even though I am getting this unresolved import warning. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks a lot and I really appreciate your help!

My app crashes when I say `.utils.constants` as it says that there is no parent package / module.

Here is my complete file structure in VSCode:

[image]
[image]
The happened with PyCharm:

[image]

Comment: I get somewhat similar issue, when developing a Django project. Sometimes some imports are not recognized by the IDE but they work just fine

Comment: Try to add a dot (.) before you say utils. The dot simply says that from the **current directory**, you have to grab the utils. Maybe that helps.

Comment: You may find that it stops working once you try to run `app.py` from outside its own folder. That is where relative imports come in, as @Soban described.

Comment: I assume you are running `app.py`. Can you include the full directory structure?

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect your queries

Answer (score 1):

I assume, Pycharm is not identifying the source root of the project. You can select the `Local Memory` directory as source root.

You can follow these steps to select the `Local Memory` as source root in Pycharm:

- Right click on the `Local Memory` from Project sidebar.
- Click on `Mark Directory as` > `Sources root`.

You do not need to add `.` before `utils` in import statement.

**Demonstration:**

I have removed similar `unresolved import` error from Pycharm.

Before selecting a directory as `Source root`, I was getting the `unresolved import` error in Pycharm like below:

[image: beofore source root]

Then I marked the `utils` folder as `source root` and the error is fixed. After the `source root` mark, the folder icon is shown as a blue folder icon like below:

[image: after source root mark]

**Reference:**

- [Pycharm documentation on Content root types](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/content-root.html#root_types)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with Pycharm.
If you want to remove the error Pycharm must scan for files to index

After indexing  it will update the python interpreter then it should work !
[image: Scanning files to index]

Good luck

Comment: It still doesn't work in both VSCode and pycharm so I'm convinced that I am doing something wrong. See my updated question